# What Am i doing wrong here 4

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of even numbers that could be formed using the numbers $2,3,4,5,6$without repeating any digit 
(a)$193$
(b)$194$
(c)$195$
(d)$196$

My solution:
 The units place can be filled in $3$ ways,the tens place in$5-1=4$ ways and hundred's place in $5-2=3$ the thousand's place in $2$ ways and ten thousand's place in $1$ way so ans is $72$ which is far from being correct. What have I missed here?

Comment: The question does not require that the numbers use all 5 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already know that for a number to be even, the last digit has to be either 2, 4, or 6. Suppose you select one of those three as the last digit, how many possible numbers with can you generate with the rest of the integers? Note that you don't need to generate numbers all with 5 digits.

Hint: Use binomial coefficients to find the number of ways to select k integers out of n integers. Multiply this with factorial k! to determine the number of integers formed using those k integers.

Example: To figure out how many numbers of 3 digits can be generated out of 8 numbers, binomial coefficient $\binom{8}{3} = 53$ which is the number of ways 3 integers out of 8 can be selected. Among each selection, I then have $3!$ ways to order them to create unique numbers of 3 digits. Therefore, the total number of 3 digits out of 8 numbers would then be $3! * 53$.

Going by this way for each digit, I came to an answer that's one of your choices.

Comment: But the numbers have to even,one have to take it into account

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How many even numbers can be made with 1,2,3,4, and 5 of the digits respectively? The total number of even numbers will just be the sum of these results.

What you have done so far is correct, but it only calculates the number of even numbers with 5 digits.

For example the total number of even numbers it is possible to make with $2$, $3$, and $4$ without repeating a digit is $10$ as we can make the numbers $2,4,32,42,24,34,432,342,324,$ and $234$.

Comment: I get the point,,,